# Angular2 Multi-page Application Consuming Spring Rest Microservices API

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular2-forms

Good day Pals, I have no experience of Angular 2, but a bit of Angularjs 1x. Having done my little research.

I found out that for a new project I am better off going for ng2.

Also, that there is better support for TypeScript against JavaScript.
This is more learning curve for me, since I am from a JS background.

In my project we have built multiple spring bootstrap rest microservices  and we need to knock out UI as speedily as possible using Angularjs2, HTML5, CSS3/Bootstrap.
I am looking for a good sample application for Angular2 showing features like: multiple page routing/navigation, templates, directives and components to implement calling our existing rest endpoints/API. Typical CRUD application references will be appreciated etc

It will be good to to see a rich client application partitioned/architectured with best practice in mind.
I have googled and there isn't much out there, I need some expert guidance please. References to code/bloggs/github etc
Thanks in advance.